# Some box-drawing character in mobile browser doesn't work

Tags: html, mobile, unicode

I try to display this character :

`╹  (#&2579;) BOX DRAWINGS HEAVY UP`

It's work on my desktop (Chrome, Firefox) but my Android mobile device can't display some box-drawing character in a browser.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character

mobile screenshot
[image: mobile display]

Can I fix this ?

Comment: The font in your android phone is outdated. If your phone supports upgrading font files, then you can upgrade it. Why do you need to display the character on one phone only, that is, your phone?

Comment: It's for a web experiment, if there is a tip to show this charactere on all device, else I found a solution (drawing a div). I have a sony Z1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, with box-drawing characters not being monospaced on Android.

I managed to fix it by using the [mononoki](https://madmalik.github.io/mononoki/) font on my website. Now all box-drawing characters are rendered properly.